# Как скопировать файл с двоеточием в имени?

Tags: linux, windows, файлы, ext4, поиск-программ

Есть раздел с файловой системой EXT4. В Windows установлен драйвер, позволяющий работать файлами на линуксовых разделах. В имени одного из файлов есть двоеточие.

Как скопировать этот файл в Windows'е на NTFS-раздел?
EXT4-раздел подключен в readonly-режиме.

Comment: Можно попробовать через консоль: copy <originalName> <newValidNtfsName>, или xcopy, она по умнее вроде. Если не поможет то похоже что никак, проверить к сожалению не на чем

Comment: @rdorn, `copy` не получилось, `xcopy` - тоже. Независимо от использования ``\\?\``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользовался программой для восстановления удалённых файлов [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva).

При этом в настройках выставил:

- Поиск неудалённых файлов, чтобы все существующие файлы попали в список.
- Отключил глубокий анализ, поскольку я знаю, что файл не удалён и нет смысла тратить время на анализ удалённого.
- Отключил восстановление структуры папок, чтобы скопировался просто один отмеченный файл без создания всей цепочки каталогов, в которых он лежит.

[image: Скриншот настроек]

Отображение результатов сделал в виде дерева, чтобы можно было легко найти нужный файл в структуре каталогов. Там он уже отображается с подчёркиваниями вместо двоеточий. А так как файл был картинкой, то справа ещё и его превью.

[image: Скриншот файла в списке]

Осталось только поставить на него флажок и "восстановить" :)

Comment: Кажется, это результат работы гномовской скриншотилки. В последних версиях Gnome по умолчанию имена уже не содержат двоеточий (а жаль)

Comment: @mymedia, не знаю, какие у тебя версии последние, но месяц назад она отказывалась сохранять файл на fat32 - похоже из-за двоеточий.