# Кавычки в имени ветки

Tags: windows, git, macos

Некий разработчик с мака залил в репозиторий ветку с кавычками в имени.
Мне эта ветка не нужна, но в Windows само её существование мешает выкачать изменения.
Что можно сделать из Windows'а в такой ситуации?

PS: С веткой уже разобрались, но хотелось бы узнать возможные решения на будущее.

Comment: `$ git checkout x\"y` ?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, а можно для тупых ссылку на строку выше? Я конечно понимаю, что "\" - это экранирование как раз кавычки. Но ещё бы про это подробнее почитать.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, у меня выкачивание изменений _другой_ ветки вызывало ошибку, связанную с существованием этой. По тепксту было похоже, что он пытается создать лок-файл по имени ветки, но ему это не удаётся из-за кавычек. Т. е. вопрос не в том, как через командную строку пропихнуть гиту параметр с кавычками внутри.

Comment: @donRumata, [можно](https://github.com/sash-kan/test/tree/x%22y)

Comment: *лок-файл по имени ветки* — а разве файлы с кавычками внутри нельзя создавать в файловых системах *fat/ntfs*? впрочем, независимо от того, можно или нельзя, вероятно, стоит сообщить об ошибке разработчикам программы git. ну или самому подрапивить нужные места в коде программы.

Comment: @donRumata, а, вас, видимо, интересует вопрос про *escape sequences*. так это всё из unix-ов растёт, и, соответственно, из [языка *c*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, во. На вику как раз то, что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: @donRumata, в винде (в bat) не так. Но там кавычки - вообще особый случай...

Answer (score 3):

среди [ограничений на имена ссылок (*refs*)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html), насколько я вижу, ничего не говорится о двойных кавычках (`"`, код `0x22` или `042`).

мне удалось повторить описанное поведение при расположении локального хранилища на файловой системе *fat* (вероятно, с *ntfs* поведение будет аналогично).

следовательно, мы наблюдаем недоработку в программе *git*: разработчики должны были предусмотреть [запрет на использование двойных кавычек](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Naming_Conventions) в именах файлов на файловых системах *fat/ntfs*. вероятно, стоит послать им сообщение об ошибке.

---

в качестве обходного варианта, возможно, подойдёт размещение локального git-хранилища на файловой системе, не имеющей такого ограничения. например, из семейства [*ext*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext).

Comment: Есть причины считать, что винда позволит использовать кавычки в именах на ext? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/572677/178988

Comment: я написал: **возможно, подойдёт**. *ms/windows* у меня нет (и не предвидится), проверить не могу. но точно я знаю одного участника ru.so, у которого есть возможность проверить (улыбка). // в приведённом примере, кстати, не заметно попыток манипуляций с двоеточием **в пределах** файловой системы семейства *ext*.